# Encoding problem in phpMyAdmin. Specifically with records containing russian text

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, phpmyadmin

I'm making small module/plugin for my future CMS/Framework. I wanted it from begining to be with multi-language support.

- I set my new database to `utf8_unicode_ci` (I read that it is more accurate, then `utf8_general_ci`)
- Set my files to UTF-8 without BOM
- Every page has in head `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8`

When I register new user new record is added to user table. I tried to register user with russian nickname. When I inserted it to form it was fine. Added record to table. Signed in and showed greetings fine in russian too. But when I looked at the record in table the nickname was some gibberish characters. I tried all encodings in browser. Nothing helped.

---

UPD: I even tried to view data with SQLyog. Shows same as phpMyAdmin.

Small screenshot of what I mean [alt text http://s43.radikal.ru/i101/1006/a9/f458f64a9918.png](http://s43.radikal.ru/i101/1006/a9/f458f64a9918.png)

---

Could anyone explain to me, what might be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean, with looking at the table record? You connect with phpmyadmin? That would seem like a problem of phpmyadmin ...

On your webpage everything is fine?

Comment: Yes. On webpage it gets data from database and displays it in russian fine. But in phpMyAdmin it shows absolute nonsense when looking at record containing russian words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an earlier answer of mine about the same problem, try that: [How to display a mysql table data in another language properly in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021769/how-to-display-a-mysql-table-data-in-another-language-properly-in-php/3021908#3021908)

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that you are describing how to display characters in any language properly in database view. Since on webpage everything is fine. Problem is when I view the records through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Eugene as a matter of fact, phpMyAdmin is just another webpage ;)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel in update I mentioned, that I also tried an application SQLyog to view the data.

Answer (score 0):

> Every page has in head Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8

is it meta tag or HTTP header? must be a latter one.

and you have to run `SET NAMES utf8` query every time you connect to the database in your PHP scripts

Comment: It's meta `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
Do you mean, that after I connect and select database I should execute query `SET NAMES utf8;`

Comment: yes, I mean you should execute query SET NAMES utf8 every time you connect and selecte database. Just add it to your connect code. And Content-Type: should be sent using header() function

Comment: Bu how does it change what I see in my database. Doesn't it change only what I get from there. And data on the webpage is fine. It shows it self incorrectly in database. I'll add a small screenshot.

Comment: 1. you have never seen your database. But just another webpage. 2. It does change what you can see in your database by telling it NOT to recode incoming symbols. Your current data is spoiled and should be deleted.

Comment: great. Thanks. After I added `SET NAMES utf8` to my SQL class as query I tried to add new user with russian nickname and everything is view fine now. Thank you very much. That was quite a pain in the as* for a while.