# phpMyAdmin not displaying special chars correctly

Tags: php, sql, encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encoding problem in phpMyAdmin. Specifically with records containing russian text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078845/encoding-problem-in-phpmyadmin-specifically-with-records-containing-russian-tex)

I ran into problems with displaying Russian characters (cyrilic) in a database. I created it first on my local - using v. 3.4.9 of pMA. Encoding of every table was set to utf8_general_ci. When I import some data from my page using a script the chars are displayed corretly in the table. When I read the data they are displayed correctly on a page.

Now I exported the dabatabase to import it to a server where the application will be served (running pMA of v. 2.10.0.2). After that I saw that the data that I already had in the table now turned into "?????" instead of Russian characters. When I try to read the data they are displayed correctly on a page but not in the database. Everything is set the same as is on my local and I cannot understand why I am seeing it differently.

Is it some issue with setting of apache server? Pls help. Thx

Comment: Could you please inspect once from your firebug and post here the header which is set in the html page

Comment: and also can you try using some other software like sqlyog and view the data whether the data is displaying properly or not

Comment: The header is set to utf-8 charset.

Answer (score 0):

after connection code in php put this code

```
 mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
```

or

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

or try this
set encoding yor page to UTF-8 with this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
```

and

```
$link=mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
mysql_set_charset(‘utf8′,$link)
```

Comment: I doing this already. No help.

Comment: I already Edit my post see it and try again

Comment: I am doing all of that already.

Comment: SOLVED: set names was actualy the problem. I removed it and it is showing the right chars now.