# Cannot save characters of my language

Tags: php, mysql, database, character-encoding

I am trying to save some data(name, last name) in my forms with php and mysql.
It's simple form like:

```
 <input type='text' name='first_name' />
```

And php gets it after submiting with:

```
$first_name = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['first_name']));
```

The problem is, that if I type characters in my languege(lithuanian), it won't save them and will change into others..
I set the language of my country, also charset in mysql is UTF-8

Any ideas where the problem is?

EDIT:
The very strange thing just happened. It started working just after I deleted all the charset=utf8 and set names utf8 :) however, thanks to everyone

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021769/how-to-display-a-mysql-table-data-in-another-language-properly-in-php/3021908#3021908

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's the MySQL connection's fault. As robertbasic said,

> As Jan said, read
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html
>   You'll most likely need to execute
>   query something like `SET NAMES utf8`
>   right after connecting to the
>   database.

For more possible causes, check [How to display a mysql table data in another language properly in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021769/how-to-display-a-mysql-table-data-in-another-language-properly-in-php/3021908#3021908) (as robertbasic said twice).

Answer (score 0):

You must send header into browser with information about page in `UTF-8` Encoding.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

or

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: setting it in the HTML is one thing, actually sending a UTF-8 document is another....

Answer (score 0):

You need the meta charset="UTF8"  and also you need your connection charset set to utf8.
Execute `mysql_query("set names utf8")` after connecting to the server.

Answer (score 0):

three things

first: the page itself must be utf-8 encoded, that is make sure that the html has the following line in the head tag somwhere:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

second: make sure that the encoding of the database and the tables is utf8

and third: after connecting to the database execute the following statement:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en, lt">
```

The LT is for Lithuanian.